# Why does my custom class for a containerView not do anything when the app is distributed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

This is probably a bit localized, but I'm having trouble with a solution I came up with. I have a few views in my app and most of them have the same layout. They have a bottom bar with some button and a top bar with a title of the view and sometimes a back button.

I tried to do this with a containerView in those views and one single view with the layout of the top bar. I then embed the top bar in the containerView of my views that need the bar. Works perfectly.

Now, to change the title in the top bar according to the view the user is currently in I made a `UIViewController` and assigned it to the top bar view. In this custom view controller I have the following:

```
#import "TopBarViewController.h"
#import "ContactViewController.h"
#import "InboxViewController.h"
#import "OutboxViewController.h"
#import "GalleryViewController.h"
#import "ApproveViewController.h"

@interface TopBarViewController ()

@end

@implementation TopBarViewController

@synthesize viewTitle;
@synthesize backButtonContainer;

UIViewController *topController;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    //This determines what the currently visible view is, copied from a StackOverflow answer
    UIWindow *topWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(UIWindow *win1, UIWindow *win2) {
        return win1.windowLevel - win2.windowLevel;
    }] lastObject];

    topController = topWindow.rootViewController;
    while (topController.presentedViewController) {
        topController = topController.presentedViewController;
    }

    //Here I set the title according to the view the user is in
    //viewTitle is an IBOutlet UILabel and is hooked up via the storyboard
    //backButtonContainer is an IBOutlet UIView and is hooked up via the storyboard
    if ([topController isKindOfClass:[InboxViewController class]]) {
        [viewTitle setText:@"Inbox"];
        [backButtonContainer setAlpha:0.0f];
    }
    else if ([topController isKindOfClass:[ContactViewController class]]) {
        [viewTitle setText:@"Contacten"];
        [backButtonContainer setAlpha:0.0f];
    }
    else if ([topController isKindOfClass:[OutboxViewController class]]) {
        [viewTitle setText:@"Outbox"];
        [backButtonContainer setAlpha:0.0f];
    }
    else if ([topController isKindOfClass:[GalleryViewController class]]) {
        [viewTitle setText:@"Controle verzenden"];
        [backButtonContainer setAlpha:1.0f];
    }
    else if ([topController isKindOfClass:[ApproveViewController class]]) {
        [viewTitle setText:@"Controle beoordelen"];
        [backButtonContainer setAlpha:1.0f];
    }
}

- (IBAction)onBackpressed:(id)sender {
    if ([topController isKindOfClass:[GalleryViewController class]]) {
        [GeneralFunctions gotoView:@"ContactViewController" fromView:self];
    }
    else if ([topController isKindOfClass:[ApproveViewController class]]) {
        [GeneralFunctions gotoView:@"ContactViewController" fromView:self];
    }
}

@end



//This is the gotoView method from GeneralFunctions, also copied from an SO answer
+(void)gotoView:(NSString*)toView fromView:(UIViewController*)fromView {
    NSString * storyboardName = @"main_ipad";
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
    UIViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:toView];
    [vc setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
    [fromView presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

This also works just the way I want it. However, when I distribute the app (in-house distribution) this entire class is not used. I tried setting alertViews in the various override functions, but nothing happens. I don't understand why there is a difference between directly compiling on the device and distributing.

What am I doing wrong here?

I'm using xcode 5.1
I'm using an iPad 4th generation for testing, running iOS7.1
I'm using 3rd and 4th generation iPad as well as an iPad Air to test the distributed app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating the view's properties a call to

```
[self.view setNeedsDisplay];
```

was required for the view to update. It signals the view to redraw with the new properties.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`isKindOfClass:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isKindOfClass%3a) to test the class of an instance, not `==`.

```
if ([topController isKindOfClass:[InboxViewController class]]) {
    ...
} else ...
```

Comment: @Kevin You asked "What am I doing wrong here?", so I answered.  Also do you understand the difference between `if/else` and a series of `if` statements?

Comment: Yes I do, but it makes no difference here, unless an instance can be of multiple class types. For the record, I changed to isKindOfClass: and changed the if's to if else's just to be completely sure. It makes no difference. I agree I should have used isKindOfClass: in the first place, but I don't think it's wrong to use ==, just not conventional.

Comment: @Kevin OK, well to the actual issue of the class not working, you will need to add breakpoints/`NSLog()`s at various points in the view controller's lifecycle (for example override `initWithNibName` or `awakeFromNib`) and concentrate on the code that instantiates this class, rather than this specific method.

Comment: I'm confused, is there a way to use breakpoint after deploying an app?? My solution is working fine while debugging (hitting the big play button in xcode). But nothing I do in this class actually happens when the app is distributed. Sorry if I sound like an asshole, I'm a bit frustrated by this.

Comment: I updated my provided code, this is the complete class. Not much to do here except change the title and back button.

Comment: @Kevin OK, so how is this view controller instantiated?

Comment: I added "[self.view setNeedsDisplay];" to the end of the method. This works. I'm still really confused about why the behaviour is different, but I guess I'm just still learning. I'm gonna delete my question now, because it probably won't help anyone in the future.